# zoom in on image of map, with highlightable sections

Tags: javascript, html, css, dictionary, imagemap

I have to do 4 things with an image for a website i am creating.

1. You should be able to zoom in and out of the image.
2. When you rollover a certain part of the image it should highlight that part.
3. When you rollover the image a tool tip should be shown.
4. When one of these rollover parts are clicked it should link to a different page

Here is the image[image]

As you can see it is quite intricate. I have a very hq version of the image which i would use for the site.

It is a image of a retail park, so when you rollover a certain retail.
Either the whole image goes dark and shows the tool tip of what retail shop you are on, or else, it just becomes more highlighted and shows the tool tip.

How would i do this in html , css and jquery?
Something like [this](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_world.html#) would be perfect, though i would need the image to be able to zoomed in on

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend finding something like google maps that will let you specify your own images. A quick search online revealed:

tutorial for google maps:
 - http://forevermore.net/articles/photo-zoom/
 - http://blog.mikecouturier.com/2011/07/create-zoomable-images-using-google.html
3rd party libraries:
- http://www.maplib.net/  (*link expired*)
- http://mashupforge.com/ (*link expired*)

I am sure there are a bunch more as well. Basically, these should give you all the functionality of google maps, but without having to recode it all yourself. You could specify boundaries and do all the normal google maps stuff and have it link out using its various api features.

Answer (score 0):

Developer of [Mashupforge](http://mashupforge.com) here. You can accomplish everything easily with Mashupforge with the exception of number 2. We don't support highlighting when you hover over a marker yet. Other than that, you just upload your source image and the app basically creates a zoomable, draggable map for you. Feel free to reach out to me if you have any questions!